# tree-mode, view selected file preview in right side window

Tags: key-bindings, directories

I am using [tree-mode](https://github.com/jonathanchu/emacs/blob/master/vendor/tree-mode.el) to see the folder contents in a tree like design.
It is working awesome. I would like to customize the enter key  behaviour.

1)  key press on a file node must show the file's contents in preview mode. Pressing enter shows the preview but the cursor is as well taken to the new window which is not desired.

2)  key press on directory nodes must expand/toggle the folder to show its contents in a sub-tree and not open the next window in dir-mode

Comment: Check out the `ranger` package from Melpa. It has this file preview feature inspired from the actual `ranger` application.

Comment: hi Kaushal, i tried to install it.. i did `package-install ranger` and then it threw error as `Symbol's function definition is void: dired-hide-details-mode`. I googled, and tried out `package-install` for `dired-details` and `dired-details+`.  And added two lines `(require 'dired-details)
(require 'dired-details+)` in my .emacs file.. still that error is existing... donno, why is `ranger` mode not resolving its dependencies during installation...

Comment: You need to be on emacs 24.4 or newer for `dired-hide-details-mode`.

Comment: It may be worthwhile for the original poster to find a real tree-view explorer for Emacs and then modify it to suit individual tastes.  I recommend taking either speedbar, neotree, ztree, etc. and customizing it -- however, this will require some advanced (but not necessarily expert) `elisp` skills.

Comment: `ztree` looks like a good bet... thanks lawlist...

Comment: I am familiar with `ztree`, and have turned it into a full-blown file manager with mark/unmark files, get-marked-files, copy/rename/delete, imenu tags (borrowing the concept from speedbar and imenu), an optional full file details view, sorting files up/down by date/size/name.  The author of `ztree` has licensing restrictions because it is now an official Emacs installable package, and I have not yet decided to sign up.  The author appears to be open to feature requests.  Consider making feature requests on Github.  If you get stuck on a modification, there is also emacs.stackexchange.

Comment: @lawlist, did you face this problem - https://github.com/fourier/ztree/issues/27

Comment: There are two similar sounding variables that are at work -- the first one is probably the one you looked at -- i.e., `ztree-diff-hidden-files-regexp` -- the second one is `ztree-hidden-files-regexp`.  Try configuring the second one, restart Emacs, and see if that does the trick.

Comment: that is a single regexp.. i am trying to have a list of extensions, that will get hidden like (".pyc" ".md" ......)

Comment: Regexp does not have to be a list, although it can be -- multiple regexp can be linked together with `\\|`.  There is really no advantage that I can see to modify the source code to support a list format (other than personal preference/taste for one format over the other), but you are certainly free to make that a feature request on Github or in a separate thread -- however, it would involve modifying the source code a bit to support examining each element of the list to create a single regexp separated by `\\|` or to compare each element of the list to each file/directory name.